# Globby and rimraf should remove everything except .yml files

Tags: javascript, node.js, zurb-foundation, yaml

The following js code (executed through foundation build) should actually clean the whole folder defined in PATHS.springDist except .yml files, instead it deletes everything.

```
function cleanSpring(done) {
    globby([PATHS.springDist + '/*', '!.yml']).then(paths => {
        paths.map(item => {
            rimraf(item, done);
        });
    });
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try to negate YML files with this: '!*.yml'

Comment: This i tried already with no result.

Comment: Has no one an idea what could be the probliem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it myself, actually i was in the wrong folder with "!*.yml"
This way it's working fine:

```
function cleanSpring(done) {
    let path = PATHS.springDist;
    globby([path+ '/**/*', '!' + path + '/*.yml']).then(paths => {
        paths.map(item => {
          rimraf(item, done);
        });
    });
}
```